# ServiceStack ApiKey

Tags: servicestack, api-key

I'm using serviceStack for my first api service.

I have my own table "**MyApiKeysTable**" where I store multiple api key for users.
I use Entity Framework.

If I use OrmLiteAuthRepository it create it's own apikey table.

What I have to do to use my own table "**MyApiKeysTable**"?

(I don't want to use OrmLite but stil continue to use EntityFramework.)

There is some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your own `ApiKey` type, [ServiceStack's API Key AuthProvider](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider) resolves its API Keys from Auth Repositories which [implement the IManageApiKeys interface](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider#imanageapikeys-api) which all ServiceStack [Auth Repositories](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#user-auth-repository) that support API Key persistence implements.

You would need to create your own Auth Repository like the [OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) and implement `IManageApiKeys` how you like, but it needs to at least return a class that inherits the `ApiKey` class.

Implementing your own Auth Repository requires a fair bit of effort, which I'd recommend against as [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) is a lightweight code-first POCO ORM that only needs its [OrmLiteConnectionFactory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#configure-ormliteconnectionfactory) configured with a db connection string, you can still use EF for the rest of your App, but I'd be taking advantage of the existing Auth Repositories.

The alternative is to ignore ServiceStack's API Key Auth Provider and implement your own that uses your preferred data access libraries, you can use [ApiKeyAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs) implementation as a guide.

Comment: If I use the implemetation provided by OrmLiteAuthRepository ther is a way to limit each apikey to a list of ip address?

Comment: Sorry but I see now that the AuthProvider generate also the USerAuth, UserAuthDetail, UserAuthRole... I already have my users table. I d'like to use my own tables, I don't want to be forced to use the table that AutProvider create. Ther is a full example ?

Comment: @MarcoStaffoli Here are some different examples for [extending built-in user tables](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#extending-userauth-tables). If you don't want to use the built-in tables you'd [need to implement a Custom Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization), basically ignore Auth repositories and have your Custom Auth Provider do its Auth/Validation within your custom implementation.